# Error in cumulative distribution function due to error in mean

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose that $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are three random variables with mean $\mu_1=5, \mu_2=3, \mu_3=1$, respectively and each with variance $\sigma = 0.1$. The joint cumulative distribution function(cdf) of these three variables is $F_{\mathbf{X}}\left(x_1,x_2,x_3\right)$. Now consider these two cases:

Case 1: Compute the cdf of $x_1$ assuming $\mu_1=5, \mu_2=3, \mu_3=1$.

Case 2: Compute the cdf of $x_1$ assuming $\mu_1=5, \mu_2=0, \mu_3=0$.

In Case 1, one can see that the cdf curve is likely to peak around $5$ or $6$. And I verified it by actually plotting it for a given family of $F_{\mathbf{X}}\left(x_1,x_2,x_3\right)$.

What do you think about the Case 2? Where do you think that the cdf may start to peak, whether before 5 or much beyond 5? I tried to plot this second scenario and I am not getting any peak even upto 20. The curve is almost flat and close to zero.

Hint: For my case these random variables are the roots of the characteristic equation of a positive definite matrix and this matrix has non-central Wishart distribution.

Comment: I don't really see how you could compute the distribution function of $x_1$ without some additional information. All we know is the mean and variance. That doesn't tell us anything about what the distribution is.

Comment: The matrix, I am using, has a non central Wishart distribution.

Comment: That is very relevant information! I suggest you add it to your post.